# How to Dual-boot Ubuntu 15.10 with Windows 10 (OLD HARDWARE! NO UEFI)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have a bootable USB that has Ubuntu 15.10 on it. I used UUI (Universal USB Installer) to do this. Keep in mind that I have a computer built in 2010 that was made to support Windows 7, but I upgraded it to Windows 10. I have an old motherboard that doesn't have an option for secure boot or whatever.

I am finally able to boot from this USB but when I get to the partition part of the installation, my partition I made (70GB) says that it is unusable. Every tutorial I watch makes this partition and when they go into the Ubuntu setup, the partition says free space, then they go about making a swap area and installing Ubuntu. In the partition tab, how come mine says unusable space?!

I made a partition, I am using a bootable USB, but it doesn't work! I have tried everything. When I try to turn my Unallocated partition into an actual usable partition in Disk Management, it won't let me either.

[image: Windows disk management screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is that, in the image shown above your 289.09GB HDD is of MBR (Master Boot record)partition style **which only supports up to 4 primary partitions** (i.e blue partitions) .

If you want more than 4 partitions then you have to create an extended partition such that the total HDD has 3 primary and 1 extended partition. Then from that extended partition you can create any number of logical extended drives in which Ubuntu can be installed.

The one thing on your system I don't understand is that why you have 2 Recovery partitions each of same size.

And also the one thing I recommend is to delete one of the primary partitions, so that you have only 3 primary partition and keep the 4th one unallocated. Now boot from the UUI (Ubuntu Live USB) and click on "**Try Ubuntu**".

Now open Gparted Partition Editor and create an extended partition of that unallocated as a logical volume and apply the changes.

Now click on Install Ubuntu and you'll see that it has the option of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 or you may use the "[**something Else**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)" option to create your own partitions.

**NOTE:** I don't recommend you to delete the Recovery Partition as it may result in the unusual booting of Windows 10, but see in the [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/) for why your PC has 2 recovery partitions.

If you need more help regarding this I will post pictures as I've also gone through this problem recently.